# Can't bind data inside a tag that has data binded already Knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout js but am getting to learn things slowly.

I have however faced a problem that can't really understand and my guess is it needs experience to understand such.

This is my problem, when I map data, CommentedDate value is not displayed. And I think it is because the span is inside h2 which is already binding data.

I am implementing this with PHP after following this [tutorial](http://techbrij.com/facebook-wall-posts-comments-knockout-aspnet-webapi) which was done using ASP and Knockout.js

```
<h2 data-bind="text: CommentedByName">
      <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: CommentedDate"></span>
</h2>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

My model:

```
function Comment(data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};

    //persisted properties
    self.CommentId = data.comment_id;
    self.PostId = data.post_id;
    self.Message = ko.observable(data.message || "");
    self.CommentedBy = data.commented_by || "";
    self.CommentedByName = data.commented_by_name || "";
    self.CommentedDate = getTimeAgo(data.comment_date);
    self.error = ko.observable();

}
```

Comment: You're rightly assuming that `it is because the span is inside h2 which is already binding data`. What have you tried instead?

Comment: When I move the span outside the h2 tag, it is working alright but that messes with the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `span` tags are allowed inside `h1` tags you can try this instead:

```
<h2>
    <span class="name" data-bind="text: CommentedByName"></span>
    <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: CommentedDate"></span>
</h2>
```

As per your comment:

```
<h2 data-bind="html: (ko.unwrap(CommentedByName) + '<span class=\'timeago\'>' + ko.unwrap(CommentedDate) + '</span>') ">
</h2>
```

Comment: This works, but it messes up with my design. I was wondering if there is a way the CommentedDate can be shown while inside the h2 tag

Comment: Personally I prefer to fix my CSS instead of messing with my HTML. I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: Getting some funny output when I try this. ' + CommentedDate + '')">

Comment: I suspect your fields are observables. Updated.

Comment: No, not really. I only  have one observable. The input field that user is supposed to type the message. This how my  model looks like; check in the original post, I have updated

Comment: What is it that you're seeing then?

Comment: Sorry I had not seen your last update. It now works perfectly fine. Thanks. I will read about the unwrap function to see what it does. Thanks again